# Change appender param value in .config files on release ( azure pipelines)

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using log4net for logging on almost all projects in my .net solution.
Currently, I have configured an appender (AzureTableAppender), configuration that is made in each project's respective app.config/ web.config. 
This appender has a param named "TableName", with an associated value that represents the table to which the data is sent. Everything works fine, but I would like to change that value for 2 of my releases as I want the logs somewhere else.
The config looks like this:

```
<log4net>
      <appender type="log4net.Appender.AzureTableAppender.......
          <param name = "TableName" value = "MyTable" />
....
</log4net>
```

To sum up, I would want to change the "TableName" value for all .config files(app, web), depending on release.
I am using Azure Pipelines for my releases . ( as I use pipeline variables from gui I thought of that, but I think those target only appSettings, connectionStrings)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#xml-variable-substitution . lots of articles\questions on this site

Comment: In Azure Devops, you can make use of the release variables section of in the releasetab.

Comment: @JamesS I think that variable substitution takes effect only on the applicationSettings, appSettings, connectionStrings

Comment: @4c74356b41 forgot that those articles had a comment section :) but there seems to be quite confusing there as the issues weren't quite resolved ( no official response after requests for more details)

Comment: Oh, my bad, I thought that the above was in `appSettings.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Replace Token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

1.Change your content of `<log4net>` element to this format:

```
<log4net>
      <appender type="log4net.Appender.AzureTableAppender.......
            <param name = "TableName" value = "#{MyTable}#" />
            <param name = "ReleaseName" value = "#{MyRelease}#" />
</log4net>
```

2.Create two variable groups(one for `DEV` and another for `Release`) with different content. In your release pipeline link them and choose corresponding scope:

[image]

When the `Replace Token task` executes, it will replace the `#{MyTable}#` and `#{MyRelease}#` with corresponding value.(Note this task won't work in files inside xx.zip file) Hope it helps and if I misunderstand your requirements, feel free to correct me.