# How to configure CI for Console Application suitable to multiple environments [ Dev, QA, Prod ]?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, console-application, azure-pipelines

I have a one legacy console application [ .Net 4.0 Framework ], I was able to build CI and it got successfully, but how to handle the CI for various environments.

Because for console applications, app.config will be turned in to .exe config and that config will be used during runtime.

I have tried creating multiple app.config's [ app.Dev.Config, app.QA.config, app.Prod.Config ] but to how to replace it during the build?

Any script to replace the app.Config with the environment-specific config?

Using **Azure Pipelines** to configure CI / CD.

Answer (score 0):

Azure devops service provides the [File Transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) to transform those config files.

You can use it in build pipeline or release pipeline, before building the project or even after building the project to transform your `app.config` file or `AppName.exe.config`.

```
-transform <path to the transform file> -xml <path to the source file> -result <path to the result file>
```

e.g： If you're trying to deploy your application to Dev stage,  you can use something like `-transform app.Dev.config -xml app.config(*.exe.config)`.

You can find more details about how to use this task in these two documents: [Guide1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) and [Guide2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#configuration-transform-file-naming-conventions).

In addition:

1.Pay attentions to the file paths! (Relative path is better in pipeline task.)

2.For CD, you may need something like `$(Release.EnvironmentName)` which represents current stage name. So `app.$(Release.EnvironmentName).config` file always contains the rules in current stage.

3.Another choice, if you define stage-scope variables in release pipeline. You can also use [Replace Token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension which replace the default values with current stage's ones. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60186136/10910450), then you don't need to keep those app.xx.config files.