# How dockerize create-react-app can access to azure release pipeline variables in docker environment

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, create-react-app, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Here is the complete flow of problem

1) Azure Build pipeline creates an artefact (docker image) using following `DockerFile`

```
FROM hub.docker.prod.private.com/library/node:10.16-alpine as buildImage
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=${REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}
ENV REACT_APP_AD_APP_ID=${REACT_APP_AD_APP_ID}
ENV REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URL=${REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URL}
ENV REACT_APP_AUTHORITY=${REACT_APP_AUTHORITY}

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

FROM hub.docker.prod.private.com/library/nginx:1.15.12-alpine
COPY --from=buildImage /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

2) And pushes docker image into Azure container registry (`ACR`).

3) Multistage Release pipeline pulls image from `ACR` and deploy on azure app service(s)
(`QA -> Stage -> Prod`).

4) Release pipeline is using variable values from variable group defined in release pipeline and I am
expecting these variable should available in docker environment so that it replaces
`ENV` variable placeholders in `DockerFile`.

But after deployment all environment variables that being used inside application remains undefined, can you please correct me if it is possible to use docker environment the way I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

> But after deployment all environment variables that being used inside
>   application remains undefined, can you please correct me if it is
>   possible to use docker environment the way I mentioned above.

The way mentioned above wasn't possible to work. During the deployment process, Release Variables **won't** **automatically** replace the original values with `stage-scope` release variables in DockerFile.

As a workaround, you can try `Replace Tokens task` from [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens), add this task in your three stages before deploy task. So the task order in your three stages should be similar to: `Replace Tokens task` to set release variables in DockerFile=>docker build and push=>deploy task.

To use this task, your Dockerfile should be:

```
ENV REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=#{REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}#
ENV REACT_APP_AD_APP_ID=#{REACT_APP_AD_APP_ID}#
ENV REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URL=#{REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URL}#
ENV REACT_APP_AUTHORITY=#{REACT_APP_AUTHORITY}#
```

Details about how this task works check my [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60186136/10910450).

If you don't want to make any change to the Dockerfile itself, another way is to pass the value in command-line arguments. You can check [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59942281/10910450) for more details.